# How to construct a variable name inside a command in LaTeX3

Tags: latex3

I have this example document structure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\examplea{mm}{
  \tl_put_right:Nn \my:ns:#1 { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\exampleb{mm}{
  \tl_put_left:Nn \my:ns:#1 { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\examplec{mm}{
  \tl_set:Nn \my:ns:#1 { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\exampled{m}{
  \tl_new:N \my:ns:#1
}

\exampled{a}
\examplec{a}{stuff}
\examplea{a}{~here}
\exampleb{a}{My~}
\typeout{\my:ns:a}

\end{document}
```

But it gives this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> \my:ns:a

l.33 \typeout{\my:ns:a}

? ^D
! Emergency stop.
<write> \my:ns:a

l.33 \typeout{\my:ns:a}
```

If I change it to this document structure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\examplea{mm}{
  \tl_put_right:Nn \my:ns:#1 { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\exampleb{mm}{
  \tl_put_left:Nn \my:ns:#1 { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\examplec{mm}{
  \tl_set:Nn \my:ns:#1 { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\exampled{m}{
  \tl_new:N \my:ns:#1
}

\NewDocumentCommand\examplee{m}{
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{}
}

\examplee{\my:ns:a}
\exampled{a}
\examplec{a}{stuff}
\examplea{a}{~here}
\exampleb{a}{My~}
\typeout{\my:ns:a}

\end{document}
```

then it prints this in the console:

```
\my:ns:a
```

when it should be printing:

```
My stuff here
```

It's only when I change it to the following document structure does it print out correctly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\examplea{mm}{
  \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\exampleb{mm}{
  \tl_put_left:Nn #1 { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\examplec{mm}{
  \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\exampled{m}{
  \tl_new:N #1
}

\exampled{\my:ns:a}
\examplec{\my:ns:a}{stuff}
\examplea{\my:ns:a}{~here}
\exampleb{\my:ns:a}{My~}
\typeout{\my:ns:a}

\end{document}
```

I would like to try and make it so the API is this:

```
\examplec{a}{stuff}
...
```

Where it's just `a` instead of `\my:ns:a`. It seems like this might have something to do with "expansion" but that is a new concept to me so I'm not sure where to start. Wondering how to make it so you can use it like `\examplec{a}{stuff}` but it defines a larger variable name such as `\my:ns:a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are constructing a name, you need the `c`-type variant of functions, for example

```
\tl_put_right:cn { my:ns:#1 } {#2}
```

---

The official naming approach for a token list variable here would be for example

```
\tl_put_right:cn { l__my_ns_ #1 _tl } { #2 }
```

(I'm assuming your token lists variables are internal, hence the `__` in the name.)